# Which Platform/Language to use for heavy computing/ML tasks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, rust, lua, julia

We built an MVP in Python Data ecosystem, but the performance is much less than desired.

Our approach:

- multiprocessing module for task parallelisation (which is awkwardly done in Python - pickle/unpickle each task)
- scikit-learn library
- pandas for data transport
- it's not about dealing with big data or training models on large data, after profiling we figured out most of the time is taken by a regular computing tasks, but we are doing a lot.

Hence:

1. We wonder what else can we use to make computing faster? After some research number of candidates popped up: Julia, Lua, Rust etc.

   - Requirements:

     - FASTER
     - Parallelisation support by design (not some workaround like Python does)
     - Existence of scientific libraries, not all of Python but major selection
     - Compiled (I guess)
2. But before we move to another platform - we wonder if there's a way of speeding up existing Python code?

Any input regarding both cases would very much be appreciated.

EDIT: Well, I think which platform/language is faster in computation has a very clear answer and I also would like to hear opinions of people experienced in other platforms.

Comment: I am quite certain this will garner opinionated answers, better to ask this question over https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's an opinion too. The question which language/platform computes faster can be answered with facts and benchmarks. I'm just not aware and don't have experience/time to compare them all by myself.

Comment: asking for software/library recommendations is explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow, you should ask somewhere else

Comment: This is an architectural question and designing good architecture is usually far beyond just programming language (there is orchestration, data flow, storage, streaming data, persistence, scalability). Nevertheless your project can be done in Julia, the speedup will be around 15-30x compared to Python and Julia indeed has all properties that you have mentioned. If you want to find out how on SO you would need to break it into several atomic questions (for example write o 4 line cross validation code in Python and ask how to parallelize in Julia etc.)

Comment: Julia (I think), Rust, C/C++ can all interface with Python, so rewriting the time-critical portions in one of those could help. You might also want to look at [cython](https://cython.org/).

Comment: As of today cython will be much for difficult to learn and far less ready for production use than Julia. Cython also assumes having some knowledge of C/C++ otherwise with any more complex code one has no chance understanding what is going on. BTW it is possible to use Scikit learn in Julia (and Julia can call natively Python and all other popular data science languages). Depending on the architecture you might also consider mixing Python with C/C++ and aforementioned Rust.